# How to make continuing of HTML new tab?

Tags: html

So, I started learning HTML few days ago, it's really easy and I understand those basics, but I didn't found the thing I currently need... So, I made a Link on my website, and when I press that link it will go to my site for example if I click "Start" it will go to "_blank" where the new things comes. So when I press that link to go there, how do I make the code that will load in that new tab, I still don't understand it. Hope you understand what I want, thank you for your help.

Comment: this is not a programming issue, flaged for off topics

Comment: To clarify, let's say your website is mysite.com and in your index.html you have a link <a href="/mypage">Link</a> and when you click it you go to a blank tab, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

`target="_blank"`   Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

`target="_self"`    Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)

`target="_parent"`  Opens the linked document in the parent frame

`target="_top"` Opens the linked document in the full body of the window

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

The  tag defines a hyperlink
Consider this example,

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

The "target" attribute specifies where to open the linked document, it can take any of the values in (_blank, _parent, _self, _top, framename) when it's value is '_blank' then the hyperlink will open in the new Tab.

Then "href" attribute will consist of the actual hyperlink, that is a URL that will open in the new page.

As you want a hyperlink for your own website, you need to give a link that works & would be served by your web server (Fro Ex., Apache). You need to put the web pages in the websever var/www/ folder if your server is linux with Apache webserver. Similarly. If you give any other website link as href, then that web page will be loaded.